# progamacion en C , Bit , obtenerlValorBit

Tags: c

tengo un problema a la hora de programar , soy nueva con la progamacion en c y no se realizar un ejercicio, a traves del programa CLion;

> **Ejercicio 5**
>
> Escribir una función obtenerValorBit que obtenga el valor de un bit concreto en la representación binaria de un número entero.
>
> La función main, para el caso 5, debe preguntar por los valores del número entero, del que se quiere obtener el valor de un bit concreto, y la posición del bit que se quiere conocer, se comienza a contar como 0 la posición más a la derecha de la representación binaria del número.
>
> *Compile el programa y pruebe el caso 5.*
>
> Elija una opción: **5**
>
> Ejercicio 5: **obtener valor de un bit**
>
> Número: **15**
>
> Posición bit: **3**
>
> Valor del bit: **1**

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada [ask] y recuerda que toda pregunta debe tener un minimo de esfuerzo por resolverlo, ademas de demostrar esto ultimo con un [example]

Comment: Pista: puedes usar el operador [`&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) para conocer la posición de un bit.

Comment: @mateo , muchas gracias , era ese operador el que me faltaba para que el codigo funcione corectamente.